# Fetching, updating and saving a record using Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data, saving-data

This question has been asked a few times on stack but I am not finding a solution for my particular situation and I have been stuck for a few hours now.

My question is: **How do I Fetch, Update and Save a record Using Core Data?**

**edit:** This question has been modified to fit the title, which is what influenced the only answer that was received. Since Stack Overflow advises against deleting posts so I decided to revise this one to benefit future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation to [create a new core data entity in swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSEntityDescription_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSEntityDescription/insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:).

Documentation to [save an `NSManagedObjectContext` in swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/save:).

To change the value of `settingsSwitch` simply change it to what it is not... so add that code to your `didChangeSwitchState` function.

Comment: the link isn't opening documentation, but I can search for it. Do I actually want to save a new object? I'll look at the links provided.

Comment: yeah sorry I copied the link from Xcode and realised it would work. I'm trying to find the latest link now for you.

Comment: Try that update and see how you get on. If you still need help let me know.

Comment: In some of the examples I've worked through I found a method for creating a new object: class func createInManagedObjectContext(moc: NSManagedObjectContext, label: String, state: Bool) -> LogItem {
        let newItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("LogItem", inManagedObjectContext: moc) as! LogItem
        newItem.settingLabel = label
        newItem.switchState = state
        
        return newItem
    }

Comment: I'm just wondering if there is a method like NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName for updating a record rather than creating a new record?

Comment: Updating an existing record is easy however I would need to understand how you are attempting to update it. And that is not what you have asked. Update your existing question or start a new question to include the relevant information.

Comment: heres the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29574073/how-do-i-update-an-existing-record-in-core-data