# How do I update an existing record in Core Data?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'd like to update a record in my database but I can't figure out how. **Specifically I am trying to fetch a record and then update/save that record with a new value when a user taps the UISwitch.**

the method where I am attempting this is in my ViewController.Swift and is called

```
didChangeSwitchState(#sender: SettingCell, isOn: Bool)
```

I am using the boiler plate CoreData template which puts the managedObjectContext in the AppDelegate.

**this is my model:**

[image]

and the resulting code plus a method for creating new entries:

**LogItem.swift**

```
class LogItem: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var settingLabel: String
    @NSManaged var switchState: Bool

    class func createInManagedObjectContext(moc: NSManagedObjectContext, label: String, state: Bool) -> LogItem {
        let newItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("LogItem", inManagedObjectContext: moc) as! LogItem
        newItem.settingLabel = label
        newItem.switchState = state

        return newItem
    }    
}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, SettingCellDelegate {

    // Retreive the managedObjectContext from AppDelegate
    let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

    // Create the table view as soon as this class loads
    //var logTableView = UITableView(frame: CGRectZero, style: .Plain)

    var logItems = [LogItem]()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let moc = self.managedObjectContext {

            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"LogItem")
            var error: NSError?

            let fetchedResults = moc.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as! [NSManagedObject]?

            if (fetchedResults?.count == 0) {

                // Create some dummy data to work with
                var items = [
                    ("Best Animal",  true),
                    ("Best Language", true),
                    ("Derp", false),
                    ("Applesauce", false)
                ]

                for (settingLabel, switchState) in items {
                    LogItem.createInManagedObjectContext(moc,
                        label: settingLabel, state: switchState)
                }
            } else {
                println("data already exists")
            }
            fetchLog()
        }
    }

    func fetchLog() {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "LogItem")

        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "settingLabel", ascending: true)

        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

        if let fetchResults = managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as? [LogItem] {

            logItems = fetchResults // question... this seems like it would store the entire table as one item in the array... huh?
        }
    }
       func save() {
        var error : NSError?
        if(managedObjectContext!.save(&error) ) {
            println(error?.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let logItem = logItems[indexPath.row]
        println(logItem.switchState)
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomSettingCell") as! SettingCell

        let logItem = logItems[indexPath.row]

        cell.settingsLabel?.text = logItem.settingLabel
        cell.settingsSwitch.on = logItem.switchState
        cell.cellDelegate = self

        return cell
    }

    func didChangeSwitchState(#sender: SettingCell, isOn: Bool) {
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(sender)
        managedObjectContext!.save(nil)
        var context = managedObjectContext

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()

        var entityName = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("LogItem", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!)

        fetchRequest.entity = entityName

        var error: NSError?

        if let cellName = sender.settingsLabel.text {
          fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "settingLabel = %@", cellName)

        }

            var fetchedResults = managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as? [LogItem]
                if let setting = fetchedResults {

                if error != nil {
                    println("An error occurred loading the data")
                } else {

                    var saveError : NSError? = nil
                    if !managedObjectContext!.save(&saveError) {
                        println("Could not update record")
                    } else {

                        tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            }
            tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

**SettingCell.swift**

```
class SettingCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var settingsLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var settingsSwitch: UISwitch!

    var cellDelegate: SettingCellDelegate?

    @IBAction func handledSwitchChange(sender: UISwitch) {

        self.cellDelegate?.didChangeSwitchState(sender: self, isOn:settingsSwitch.on)

    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    } 
}
```

**SettingItem.swift**

```
class SettingItem: NSObject {

    var settingName : String?
    var switchState : Bool?

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    init (settingName: String?, switchState : Bool?) {
        super.init()
        self.settingName = settingName
        self.switchState = switchState
    }
}
```

**SettingCellDelegate.swift**

```
protocol SettingCellDelegate {
    func didChangeSwitchState(# sender: SettingCell, isOn: Bool)
}
```

finally this is my output,

[image]

Comment: nicely written question BTW!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not changing the value of the LogItem before saving. Please do it accordingly, also this code may generate **compiler errors** as I'm not well-versed in the swift language, I just write the pseudo code that may help you.

```
var fetchedResults = managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as? [LogItem]
if let setting = fetchedResults {
  if error != nil {
    println("An error occurred loading the data")
  }
  else {
    //now you have array of LogItem in your case it's one (assuming that you have unique name
    //change the item's switch state and then save it
    //Please make a count check here before getting the object
    /*
    if count == 0 -->> record doesn't exist
    else -->> record exist
    */
    var settingLogItem = setting[0]
    settingLogItem.switchState = isOn

    var saveError : NSError? = nil
    if !managedObjectContext!.save(&saveError) {
      println("Could not update record")
    }
    else {
      tableView.reloadData()
    }
  }
}
```